# csv.writer writes strings with quotes to file instead of the actual string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list to file. And csv.writer writes the strings with quotes even if they have no quotes around them. I used .strip to take the quotes out and when I check by printing it prints just fine.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
##############################################################################
Scrape wiki pages with localities in the US.
'''

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# list of all links to scrape:

linkList = [
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Alabama',

]

def scrapeSite():
    scrape = []    
    for link in linkList:
        
        #inside location
        page = requests.get(link)   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

        table = soup.find_all(scope="row")
        for el in table:
            title = el.find('a')
            try:
                loc = []
                string = title['title'].strip('"')
                loc.append(string)
                scrape.append(loc)
            
            except TypeError:
                pass
          
    return scrape



filename = 'localities.csv'

scrape = scrapeSite()

def saveFile(scrape, filename):

    with open(filename, 'wb') as csvfile:
            
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',)
       
            writer.writerow(['Name']) 
            for loc in scrape:  
                writer.writerow(loc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    saveFile(scrape, filename)
```

Comment: try `writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
`

Answer (score 1):

To issue quotes only when absolutely needed, add the `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` or `csv.QUOTE_NONE` parameter when creating the writer:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

There are subtle differences for writers but for basic usage they're the same:

> csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any of the characters in lineterminator.
>
> csv.QUOTE_NONE : Instructs writer objects to never quote fields. When the current delimiter occurs in output data it is preceded by the current escapechar character. If escapechar is not set, the writer will raise Error if any characters that require escaping are encountered.

Even `csv.QUOTE_NONE` issues quotes when the data *must* be quoted (ex: quotes in the data, that would render the csv unreadable if not escaped.